# POST array in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

My problem is

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../ajax/si-notificar_investigacion.php",
    data: {
        idincidente: $("#idincidente").val(),
        arrControlls : arrControlls
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(datos) {
        alert(datos);

    }
});
```

this is my ajax

Now I use `arrControlls` variable as array which is comes from another function

now if `arrControlls` is like

```
[0] = "test1";
[1] = "test1";
[2] = "test1";
```

then it is okey I get this variable as an array in action page

BUT 
if I use value like this

```
['sid_1'] = "test1";
['sid_2'] = "test1";
['sid_3'] = "test1";
```

then I do not get variable in action page 
WHY?

adding this lines for more detail

I am using jquery function for getting data

```
function getAllControllValue()
{

    var  arrControlls = new Array();
    $("#container-div input").each(function(){
        arrControlls[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).val();
    });
    return arrControlls;
}
```

Comment: Arrays can't have keys, they are indexed with numbers only.

Comment: then what to do for keys ?

Comment: Use objects (which your array will be converted to anyway), but that probably means the structure of the data sent to the server changes as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are expected to have sequential, numeric indexes. That is what they are for. You can give them named properties, but tools designed to do something with the data in the array tend to ignore them.

Given an array anywhere in `data`, jQuery will only pay attention to the numeric indexes.

If you want to have named keys, then use a plain object.

Initialise `arrControlls` with `{}` not `new Array()`.

Comment: You are correct I just replace [] with {} and all the data are listed in action page thanks I mean new array

Answer (score -1):

User JSON.stringify like this:
`JSON.stringify(arrControlls)`

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "../ajax/si-notificar_investigacion.php",
    data: {
        idincidente: $("#idincidente").val(),
        arrControlls : JSON.stringify(arrControlls)
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    async: false,
    success: function(datos) {
        alert(datos);

    }
});
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? After doing this.

Comment: Not have any value in array in POST no error comming

Comment: `JSON.stringify` will also ignore named properties on arrays.

Comment: typeof Array !== type Object @pritzzz